# knife environment from file changes filename

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I am trying to upload a chef environment using the knife command but it changes the filename and I am not sure why. Can someone please suggest a solution?

```
[centos@ip-10-$$$-***-6 .chef]$ knife environment  from file /home/centos/jenkins-do-not-delete/workspace/chef-repo/generateEnvironmentfromTemplate/GIT/InfaEnvJsonGenerator/InfaEnvJsonGenerator/chefOutput/Merged/Release-Azure-R35-pod1-services.json
Updated Environment Release-Azure-R35-pod-services
```

If you see carefully, my file name is `Release-Azure-R35-pod1-services.json`

but it was changed to `Release-Azure-R35-pod-services.json`

The numeric 1 was removed from pod1

Comment: `cat Release-Azure-R35-pod1-services.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name has no relevance. The environment name is the value of the name parameter within the Release-Azure-R35-pod1-services.json file.